# Backwards compatibility when changing base class

Tags: .net, backwards-compatibility

In .NET, do I maintain binary compatibility when I set a new base class for a class that earlier didn't have any base class (inherits from System.Object)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test suggests it's okay, but personally I'd be *very* nervous of doing this without recompilation. You would basically be in a state which you couldn't reproduce from source code without going through the same steps - build the library, build the calling code, change the library, rebuild just the library code.

Behaviour can change in subtle ways with things like extension methods and overloading. It's *much* cleaner if you can rebuild all the calling code as well, so you're on firmer ground when it comes to debugging etc. If you find there's a bug in some interaction between the library and the calling code, you'd have to be *really* careful about how you analysed, tested and debugged it, if you couldn't just rebuild everything and get the same results.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any problem unless the base class changes the old behavior in some way.